# Problems with "redo/undo" function(mfc, c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, undo-redo

I'm trying to create Redo/Undo function in my mfc application, but when i'm trying to undo CLine object - it doesn't work correctly. What i do wrong? Sorry for my english!

[image]

```
void CKonokhovDoc::OnEditUndo()
{
// TODO: Add your command handler code here
int Index = (int)m_LineArray.GetUpperBound();
int Index2 = (int)m_LineArray_redo.GetUpperBound();
if (Index>-1){
    redoLine = m_LineArray.GetAt(Index);
    m_LineArray_redo.SetAt(Index2+1,redoLine);
    m_LineArray.RemoveAt(Index);
 }
UpdateAllViews(0);
SetModifiedFlag();
}


void CKonokhovDoc::OnUpdateEditUndo(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
// TODO: Add your command update UI handler code here
pCmdUI->Enable((int)m_LineArray.GetSize());

}


void CKonokhovDoc::OnEditRedo()
{
// TODO: Add your command handler code here
int Index = (int)m_LineArray.GetUpperBound();
int Index2 = (int)m_LineArray_redo.GetUpperBound();
m_LineArray.SetAt(Index+1, m_LineArray_redo.GetAt(Index2));
m_LineArray_redo.RemoveAt(Index2);
//redoLine = NULL;
UpdateAllViews(0);
SetModifiedFlag();
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code as text?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, already..!

Comment: Thanks! Where specifically does it crash? When you undo? Or redo?

Comment: @Rakete1111  - On Undo !

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thank you for trying solve my problem!
I'm change "SetAt" to "Add" and now all work fine/

Comment: When you see an assert window, click on "retry" which will show you the source code where the assert happened and looking at that source code will usually give you a hint of what is wrong.

Comment: More important than the immediate source code is the call stack. It will eventually point to **your** code that is responsible for the failed debug assertion. Besides that, code that contains variables named `Index` and `Index2` is needlessly hard to read. Bugs are just a natural progression from there.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `SetAt` accessed an out of bounds index, which resulted in a assert call from VS. Using `Add` naturally solves the problem, as the array is extended.

<sub>[This was mentioned by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575690/problems-with-redo-undo-functionmfc-c?noredirect=1#comment66462113_39575690)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine

```
void CLab1_LeshikDoc::OnEditUndo()
{
    int Index = (int)m_LineArray.GetUpperBound();
    int Index2 = (int)m_LineArray_redo.GetUpperBound();
    if (Index>-1) {
        m_LineArray_redo.Add(m_LineArray.GetAt(Index));
        m_LineArray.RemoveAt(Index);
    }
    UpdateAllViews(0);
    SetModifiedFlag();
}


void CLab1_LeshikDoc::OnUpdateEditUndo(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable((int)m_LineArray.GetSize());
}

void CLab1_LeshikDoc::OnRedo()
{
    int Index2 = (int)m_LineArray_redo.GetUpperBound();
            m_LineArray.Add(m_LineArray_redo.GetAt(Index2));
            m_LineArray_redo.RemoveAt(Index2);
    UpdateAllViews(0);
    SetModifiedFlag();
}

void CLab1_LeshikDoc::OnUpdateRedo(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable((int)m_LineArray.GetSize());
}
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, it would help others reading your answer if you gave some comments/explanation as what your doing and why.